# Google drive read and edit a file and automate login .NET

Tags: c#, winforms, google-drive-api

in c# I want to read and write to a file on google drive, I see that most example applications use a console to collect the args that come back from the login attempt.  I want to do this in a winforms app.

```
        String CLIENT_ID = "XXXX";
        String CLIENT_SECRET = "XXXX";

        // Register the authenticator and create the service
        var provider = new NativeApplicationClient(GoogleAuthenticationServer.Description, CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET);
        var auth = new OAuth2Authenticator<NativeApplicationClient>(provider, GetAuthorization);
        var service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            Authenticator = auth
        });

        File body = new File();
        body.Title = "My document";
        body.Description = "A test document";
        body.MimeType = "text/plain";

        byte[] byteArray = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("document.txt");
        System.IO.MemoryStream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(byteArray);

        FilesResource.InsertMediaUpload request = service.Files.Insert(body, stream, "text/plain");
        request.Upload();

        File file = request.ResponseBody;
```

When it comes to the authorization I want to avoid the need for the user to copy and paste the code that comes back, I've heavily used the google sample helper but there must be a simpler way!

private static IAuthorizationState GetAuthorization(NativeApplicationClient client)
        {

```
        const string STORAGE = "XXXX";
        const string KEY = "XXXX";
        string scope = "";

        // Check if there is a cached refresh token available.
        IAuthorizationState state = AuthorizationMgr.GetCachedRefreshToken(STORAGE, KEY);
        if (state != null)
        {
            try
            {
                client.RefreshToken(state);
                return state; // Yes - we are done.
            }
            catch (DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.ProtocolException ex)
            {
                //CommandLine.WriteError("Using existing refresh token failed: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }

        // Retrieve the authorization from the user.
        state = AuthorizationMgr.RequestNativeAuthorization(client, scope);
        AuthorizationMgr.SetCachedRefreshToken(STORAGE, KEY, state);
        return state;
    }
```

What do I need to do to get this working?  What is the "scope" meant to be set as?

Ive read countless articles and it doesnt seem to be easy, does anyone have an example winforms app example>?

Answer (score 0):

what a dullard!!

string scope = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive";

The above code works - just blame it on coding at 3 in the morning ...